# php shortcut between echo

Tags: php

I've two php shortcuts in a div class.
I have to keep both shortcuts in the same class.
If user is logged i need to show only the second and hide the first. Being obviously impossible insert div class= between echo (i must keep a unique class too) and also impossible something like this :

```
<div class="login">
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
echo '<?php do_action('facebook_login_button');?>';
} 
else {
echo '';
}?>
<?php the_widget('Sidebar_Login_Widget');?>
</div>
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: You're going to need to rephrase the question. Also `echo '<?php ` seems like an error..

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. Why are you trying to echo `<?php ?>` tags as strings?

Comment: that should outright throw you a parse error

Comment: I think he's trying to interpolate strings. I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your quoting is wrong, and you don't need to enter PHP again when you're already in PHP. Simply just use the function.

```
<div class="login">
    <?php
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (0 == $current_user->ID) {
        echo do_action('facebook_login_button');
     } 
     the_widget('Sidebar_Login_Widget'); ?>
</div>
```

Also removed the `else`-block, as it did basically nothing.

*I'm not too familiar with WordPress, not sure if you even need to echo the `do_function()`*